# Context disposed error with Autofac DI and Repository pattern

Tags: c#, autofac

Am building web application using MVC, Auto fac Dependency Injection and Repository pattern datacontext. Iam trying to retrieve values in one of the table asynchronously but i get the error Object disposed for that table.

```
private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)  
{ 
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterType<DBEntities>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityRepository<>))
               .As(typeof(IEntityRepository<>))
               .InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<TableNameClassFile>().As<ITableNameClassFile>().InstancePerRequest();

}
```

Database call

```
private readonly ITableNameClassFile tableNameClass

public Test(ITableNameClassFile _tableNameClass)
{
    tableNameClass = _tableNameClass;
}

public async void GetData()
{
    try
    {
        await tableNameClass.QueryableData()
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
     // I get the error corresponding table object exposed error
    }

}
```

How to involve in database related activity asynchronously with Auto fac DI and Repository pattern.

Comment: check this
https://codingfiasco.wordpress.com/2016/05/30/entity-frameworks-dbcontext-disposal-in-web-api-async/

Comment: That `async void` method is very suspicious. However, we cannot help you without a [mcve] as it's not clear at all how is that called from ASP.NET MVC

Comment: You probably don't handle the lifecycle from the context correctly. I assume the table-class lives in the repository layer, so you a context to communicate to the database. SInce that is a disposable object, you need to use it correctly.

Comment: Where is the dbcontext registered at all I ask myself? Please provide more code.